# Cannot figure how to use git pull

Tags: git, push, pull

I am new to github and began all work on my imac and did some extra work on my laptop. I managed to pull to the laptop but now need to push the current info to the repo. I am doing cd /users/.... and it shows that I am on the right file but when I type git status I get "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: Are you in the same directory as your local working copy? If  so, have you run a `git init`?

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to pull to the laptop

Make sure you **[clone your GitHub repo](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-repositories/#cloning)** first, and report your modifications in the folder in which you have cloned the GitHub repo.
That way, you will be able to push because:

- it is a git repo
- it has an [**upstream repo**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) already set.